# PHP Sticky Form for Drop Down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, sticky

I am having trouble making my drop down sticky (to make it so that after the form is submitted the first time, the selection chosen will be pre-selected in the form on the following page). I removed some code I deemed irrelevant. I tried making the value $_GET['continent'] but that didn't work.  Does anyone have any thoughts? See function createpulldown

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <title>Homework 14</title>  
 </head>
 <body>


<?php 
if (isset($_GET['submitted']))
    handleform($_GET['country']);

displayform("country");

?>
</body>

function displayform($menuname) {
    echo "<fieldset><legend>Select a continent and I will show you information from the CIA about it.</legend>
            <form method = 'get'>";
            createpulldown($menuname);
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submitted' value='Search'>
            </form>
          </fieldset>";
}

function createpulldown($menuname) {
    echo "<select name='$menuname'>";
    $dbc = connectToDB();
    $query = "SELECT Continent FROM countries GROUP BY Continent";
    $result = performQuery($dbc, $query);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $continent = $row['Continent'];

        if (isset($_GET[$menuname]))
            echo "<option name='continent' value = $continent selected>$continent</option>\n";
        else
            echo "<option name='continent' value = $continent>$continent</option>\n";
    }

    echo "</select>";
    disconnectFromDB($dbc, $result);
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry; to make it so that after the form is submitted the first time, the selection chosen will be pre-selected in the form on the following page.

Comment: Ah ok. Well personally I don't know how to do that. I suggest you edit your question with what you mentioned above. Cheers

Comment: I would use HTML5 local storage, this explains it pretty well: http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/using-html5-local-storage-and-jquery-to-persist-form-data-47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the value retrieved from $_GET is equal to one of the option values.

Try this for your while statement:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $continent = $row['Continent'];
    if ($_GET[$menuname] == $continent)
        echo "<option name='continent' value='$continent' selected>$continent</option>\n";
    else
        echo "<option name='continent' value='$continent'>$continent</option>\n";
}
```

I also fixed a syntax error.  You need to wrap your option values in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $continent = $row['Continent'];

    if (isset($_GET[$menuname]))
        echo "<option name='continent' value = $continent selected>$continent</option>\n";
    else
        echo "<option name='continent' value = $continent>$continent</option>\n";
}
```

You are checking here, if a GET parameter named $menuname was passed to your script – but this is the same for all options you create, either the parameter is there o not.

What you want to do instead, is compare the value of the parameter to the current $continent value you are writing – if they are equal, select the current option, if not, don’t.